# "Selecting" or "Wrapping" an IQueryable so that it is still queryable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

I have a Class / API that uses an `IQueryable<FirstClass>` data source however I wish to expose an `IQueryable<SecondClass>`, where `SecondClass` is a wrapper class for `FirstClass` that exposes nearly identical properties, however for various reasons needs to inherit from an unrelated base class.  For example:

```
// My API
void IQueryable<SecondClass> GetCurrentRecords()
{
    return from row in dataSource
           /* Linq query */
           select new SecondClass(row);
}

// User of my API
var results = GetCurrentRecords().Where(row => row.Owner = "Mike");
```

Now I can make the above compile simply by using `AsQueryable` however I want to expose a "true" `IQueryable` that efficiently queries the database based on the API users query.

I know that this isn't trivial (my wrapper IQueryable implementation needs to understand the relationship between the properties of `SecondClass` and `FirstClass`), and that it has nothing to do with the `Select` function, but it *seems* like it should be possible.

How do I do this?

**Note:** I know that instead my API could just expose `FirstClass` along with a helper method to convert `FirstClass` to `SecondClass` for when the API user is "done" creating their query, but it feels messy and I don't like the idea of exposing my generated classes in this way.  Also I'd like to know how to do the above anyway just from a purely academic standpoint.

Comment: This question is meaningless without the code you haven't included. L2E already does this for `ObjectQuery<T>`. Your own code (producing `dataSource` might not, but you haven't shown that.

Comment: @Craig I don't follow - what is it that you need to see? `dataSource` is just a generated class that inherits from `ObjectQuery<FirstClass>`.  Are you saying that this should *already work*? What is this magic!?!

Comment: If `dataSource` is an `ObjectQuery<FirstClass>` then your query will fail at runtime since L2E doesn't support parameterized constructors. But the "magic" is [LINQ to Entities projections,](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/12/31/38500/) which already return  `IQueryable<T>` and support further composition with SQL support.

Comment: see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/03/01/tip-55-how-to-extend-an-iqueryable-by-wrapping-it.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you should return not an IQueriable, but Expression. Then you will be able to modify expression and let LINQ generate a query from a final Expression object. Example is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx